# change class according to value from database

Tags: javascript, jquery

kinda got lost here, i want to change a class='label' according to the data pulled out of db with Django. So according to {{account.status}} I will have either class='label-danger' or 'label-info'

My .js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if($('#label').attr('value').val() == 'New'){
        $('#label').addClass('label-info');
    };
    else($('#label').attr('value').val() == 'Rep'){
        $('#label').addClass('label-warning');
    };
    else($('#label').attr('value').val() == 'Progress'){
        $('#label').addClass('label-success');
    };
 });
```

My Html:

     {{account.status}}

Comment: Your question is unclear. I don't know what you're asking.

Comment: I am asking how to change class based on value from db, which in my case is account.status, could be either "New", "Rep", or "Progress"

Comment: How are you getting your value from db?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this

PHP:

```
<?
$getClass = mysql_query("SELECT class FROM myTable");
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($getClass)){
  $class = $rows["class"];

?>

<h1 class='<?php echo $class; ?>' >Hello</h1>

<?

}
?>
```

I think is may work,but i don't test this yet,still hope it can deal with you job